# Set instance variable in main after including module?

Tags: ruby

Here's my module which tries to set an instance variable. I'm trying both initialize and self.included but neither are working when I do the include on the outermost (`main`) scope:

```
module Asd
  def initialize
    @asd = 0
  end
  def self.included(base)
    @asd = 0
  end
  attr_reader :asd
end
```

Including it in a class works, and I can read the instance variable:

```
class Bsd
  include Asd
end
Bsd.new.asd
# => 0
```

But doing this at global level doesn't work:

```
include Asd
@asd
# => nil
asd 
# => nil
```

I know often times people will question motivation for putting their code at the global level. In this case I just want to see how it is done.

Comment: I believe `initialize` is only run when you create an instance. `Asd` is a module and you can't have an instance for a module. Then, when you include `Asd` at global level like you did, you just won't have `initialize` run.

Comment: As for the `asd` method... I really don't know why you get a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: I am running `ruby 2.3.0p0`, and calling `include Asd` and then `asd` gives me `nil`, not `NoMethodError`. You can use `ls -pv` command under [Pry REPL](http://pryrepl.org/) to investigate whether method has been defined or not.

Comment: The `@asd` inside the `self.included` method is not the same as the one inside `initialize`. Different contexts.

Comment: EddeAlmeida & tewu you're right; my mistake; have edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@EricDuminil explained why your approach didn't work. Here's how you can make it work in this context: set instance variable directly, without initializer.

```
module Asd
  def self.extended(base)
    base.instance_variable_set(:@asd, "Another @asd")
  end

  attr_reader :asd
end

@asd # => nil # !> instance variable @asd not initialized

extend Asd # extend, not include.

@asd # => "Another @asd"
asd # => "Another @asd"
```

Comment: Ahah, I was writing just that for the 2nd part of my answer. No need for it anymore!

Answer (score 4):

I hope this code makes it a bit clearer :

```
module Asd
  def initialize
    puts "# Initializing"
    @asd = "One @asd"
  end

  def self.included(base)
    puts "# Importing into #{base}"
    @asd = "Another @asd"
  end
  attr_reader :asd
end

class Bsd
  include Asd
  # => # Importing into Bsd
end

puts Bsd.new.asd
# =>
# Initializing
# One @asd

puts Asd.instance_variable_get(:@asd)
# => Another @asd

include Asd
# => # Importing into Object

puts self.asd.inspect # Method is defined for main, @asd hasn't been initialized because main was instantiated before the script was launched
# => nil

puts Object.new.asd
# =>
# Initializing
# One @asd
```

Basically, your code is too late for `main`. It has already been initialized before the script was launched, so no code inside `initialize` will be launched for main anymore.